# Is there a way to change the shapefile being used in exportPdf() function?

Tags: qgis, python, print-composer, atlas

I'm using this function to export layouts and I want to know if it's possible to switch the shapefiles(.shp) being used in the Atlas project for other ones before the function actually exports the atlas layouts to PDF, as if I changed the .shp file in the folder where the `prj_atlas.qgz` gets the project's source files from:

Below is the function being used to export to PDF:

```py
def export_pdf(self, layout_name):
        atlas_project_path = QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath() + r'\python\plugins\spu_intersect\atlas\prj_atlas.qgz'
        fld_output = self.dlg.txt_output.text()
        layout_name = layout_name
        QgsProject.instance().read(atlas_project_path)
        layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(layout_name)
        atlas = layout.atlas()
        map_atlas = atlas.layout()

        pdf_settings = QgsLayoutExporter(map_atlas).PdfExportSettings()
        pdf_settings.dpi = 150

        for layout in QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().printLayouts():
            if layout.name() == layout_name:
                if atlas.enabled():
                    pdf_settings.rasterizeWholeImage = True
                    result, error = QgsLayoutExporter.exportToPdfs(atlas, fld_output + '\\' + "name",
                                                           settings=pdf_settings)
                    if not result == QgsLayoutExporter.Success:
                        print(error)
                atlas.endRender()

        QgsProject.instance().clear()
```

This line contains the path to the atlas project that I want to change the shape files being used:

`atlas_project_path = QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath() + r'\python\plugins\spu_intersect\atlas\prj_atlas.qgz'`